# Find unmatched records using inner join without using WHERE clause

Tags: sql, join

I have a tables `Table1` and `Table2` like this:

**Table1**

```
Col1
====
A
B
```

**Table2**

```
Col1
====
A
B
C
D
```

Now using an `INNER JOIN` I need to find unmatched records from `Table2`

(Note: `WHERE` clause is **NOT ALLOWED**)

**Expected output:**

```
Col1
====
C
D
```

What can be the SQL Query for this?

I have already tried following its not working.

```
Select Distinct 
    Table2.col1
from 
    Table1 
Inner Join 
    Table2 On Table1.col1 <> Table2.col1
```

Comment: I posted an answer using a RIGHT JOIN, no WHERE clause.  I can't see how INNER JOIN will allow you find unmatched records; it's point is to find equality.

Answer (score 0):

Jumped the gun the first time - should have read properly, sorry.  Had to think about this one:

```
SELECT      Table2.col1
FROM        Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2
            ON  Table1.col1 = Table2.col1
GROUP BY    Table1.col1, Table2.col1
HAVING      Table1.col1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: is a having clause permitted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Table2
WHERE Col1 NOT IN 
    (SELECT Col1 FROM Table1)
```

The following query also works

```
   SELECT Col1 FROM Table2
   EXCEPT
   SELECT Col1 FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

nobody said it had to be sensible did they?

```
with
t1 as (
        select col1 as c1
             , row_number() over (order by col1 ASC) as rn1
        from table1
      ),
t2 as (
        select col1 as c2
             , row_number() over (order by col1 DESC) as rn2
        from table2
      )
select
   c2 as Col1
from t2
inner join t1 on t2.rn2 = t1.rn1 and t2.c2 <> t1.c1
order by c2 ASC
;
```

---

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4747e/1 (postgres 9.3.1)